# Brown around edge of Avocado leaf

Tags: diagnosis, avocado

I have been growing an avocado tree from the pit indoors for roughly 6 months. It seems to be growing strong as it has beautiful large leaves and many new sprouts (after I pruned it). I also have a 6000K grow light which I am using since the window isn't getting a ton of light (Canadian Winters are dark).

I transplanted it into a large felt-like grow bag [similar to this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VWU2UDC).

I am noticing some browning on some of the lower leaves. Here is an example of what I am referring to:

[image: browning on leaf]

Some of the bigger leaves also have a small amount of brown right at the tip of the leaf.

I don't think I have been over watering the plant as I usually stick my finger down into the soil and make sure it is pretty dry before I water it again (as I have read to do - maybe I am wrong here).

**Any thoughts on what this could be and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it is worth I too have avocados in Canada, with no supplemental lighting in a south facing window, use regular garden soil with a good proportion of sand mixed in and water by dunking the entire pot into several inches of plain water without waiting for the soil ball to dry out. I never fertilize but regularly move to a slightly larger pot with fresh soil each spring. The leaves on mine show a little lighter green in mid leaf than close to the vein, but otherwise all normal except for minor physical damage or occasional insect chewing since they live outside most of the summer.

I think maybe you are letting the soil ball dry out too much. If the root ball drains down fairly quickly then water as often as you like, making sure to allow it to drain fully immediately afterwards. Otherwise the leaf in the image looks very good for nutrients, so no action required there.

Comment: Okay I will give this a go. Thanks for the advice. I will try to water a little more frequently. It is good to know there are some other avocado growers in Canada!

Another interesting point about bringing it outside in the summer. Have you written about your experience with this anywhere? I am intrigued. Once it is consistently warm outside, can you just leave it out there? Do you give it direct sunlight or have any special instructions? I upvoted your response but it will not go through due to low experience points on my end